# straight lines on spherical surfaces

Tags: geometry

I'm not sure how to explain this so here goes. I want to place a horizontal line of text on the side of a curved brandy glass. Is there a formula that can be applied to ensure the text stays horizontal and in a perfectly straight line when the text is applied at a specific point up or down the glass from a flat sheet of paper? (ie I want to print it on paper in the correct curve so when applied to the glass it will appear straight).I suppose the same formula could be used on a tapered glass?? Thoughts or a definitive answer would be great.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you write text on a sheet of paper, and then roll it up into a cylinder or cone, if it seems "straight" or not will depend on perspective (the position of the viever's eye).

In the case of a cone (presumably the form of a glass you have in mind), it will look "straight" to someone looking perpendicular to the axis if it follows a circle at constant distance from the cone's point.

Comment: The idea is, using the glass, to ensure that the line or text remains parallel to the top of the glass. If the glass tapers inwards at the top then the curve, when printed on a flat paper, will appear upturned at the ends. WhEn applied to the glass surface it will be parallel to the rim. Thanx